# How to have locatedb created / updated automatically?

Tags: command-line, automation

I ran `locate blob.txt` and I got:

```
$ locate .bashrc

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

I ran this command and my locate database was built within a few minutes (includes tens of thousand of files).

On my Linux (Ubuntu) system my locatedb database is updated automatically by default, on a daily basis I believe.

How do I turn this on for my Mac?

Comment: While this could work, did you consider using the spotlight feature to find a file : `mdfind -name blob.txt`?

Comment: Interesting option.  I tend to stick to methods that will work pretty much the same in Ubuntu.  Best of all are tricks like alt-tab that work in all 3 OS's, i.e. Winodws too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run that command, launchd will update the database every week automatically. On my system, the plist is set to run every Saturday at 3:15am.

Edit from OP: Yes, works, note: Also it ran once when submitted, so for me, within a few minutes I was able to use `locate`.  the update process runs in the background so you may have to wait a few minutes before locate then works (You'll get the "`The locate database ... does not exist`" message until then).

Answer (score 2):

`com.apple.locate.plist` is a launch daemon with a predefined schedule:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
  <key>Hour</key>
  <integer>3</integer>
  <key>Minute</key>
  <integer>15</integer>
  <key>Weekday</key>
  <integer>6</integer>
</dict>
```

This means that it runs every Saturday (`Weekday`=`6`) at 3:15.

You can edit these values in the plist to modify the schedule to your liking. Removing the `Weekday` key will mean that it runs every day of the week, if you need it to run more often.